# Include a PowerShell file inside a ScriptBlock

Tags: powershell, scriptblock

I have written the following code

```
$sb = {
    . .\Myfunctions.ps1
    $x = MyFunction1
    $y = MyFunction2
    $x + $y
}

$cred = Get-Credential "domain\user"

Invoke-Command -Computer localhost -Credentials $cred -ScriptBlock $sb
```

This does not work because it says The term .\MyFunctions.ps1 is not recognized as commandlet

Why can't I include a file inside a script block?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the `$pwd` (current directory) in the script block is different from the actual console path casued this because you are using `invoke-command` with `-computer` parameter is like you are do it in a remoting session. Try to put full path to your script to call it or just use ( if locally) `& $sb`